# Why does if(!(cin >> int)) accept a decimal number in the first iteration but not the other ones?

Tags: c++, if-statement, int, decimal, cin

The following program is from a google tutorial and it's pretty straightforward, except when I input a decimal number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int input_var = 0;
  do {
    cout << "Enter a number (-1 = quit): ";

    if (!(cin >> input_var)) {
      cout << "You entered a non-numeric. Exiting..." << endl;
      break;
    }

    if (input_var != -1) {
      cout << "You entered " << input_var << endl;
    }

  } while (input_var != -1);

  cout << "All done." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

if the input is an int (not -1) it outputs:

```
Enter a number (-1 = quit): 5
You entered 5
Enter a number (-1 = quit):
```

if it is a non-numeric:

```
Enter a number (-1 = quit): p
You entered a non-numeric. Exiting...
All done.
```

and that's exactly how it is supposed to work, but if it is a decimal number:

```
Enter a number (-1 = quit): 5.9
You entered 5
Enter a number (-1 = quit): You entered a non-numeric. Exiting...
All done.
```

I know how c++ behaves if you assign a `double` or a `float` to an `int` and in this case it outputs the truncated decimal number the first time and `cin` does not become `false` but the second iteration it does not even accept an input.

I would understand if it didn't accept it from the very beginning or if it just truncated the decimal and behaved the same as if it had had an `int` as input but why does it behave differently the first loop and differently the second loop?

Comment: A good default for iostreams input is to use `getline`, from the `<string>` header.

Comment: What do you mean by 'a decimal number'? Do you mean base-10? because that's the only thing it really means.

Comment: @EJP It also means "a non-integer value expressed with a decimal point". It is part of the definition of the tag "decimal" in my question. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know how C++ behaves if you assign a `double` or a `float` to an `int` and in this case it outputs the truncated decimal number.

That is not actually what's happening here. There is no assigning of a `float` or `double` value to your `int`. When you attempt to *input* an integer of `5.9`, it successfully gets the `5` bit and stops there, leaving `.9` in the input stream. At no stage have you extracted the full `5.9` from the input stream and truncated it to an integer for putting into `input_var`.

Then, on the *next* iteration, it finds `.9`, figures out that it's not a valid integer, and acts accordingly, the same as when you entered `p`.

This is covered in C++14, section `22.4.2.1 num_get()` in excruciating detail but the bottom line is in stage 3 of that description:

> The sequence of chars accumulated in stage 2 (the field) is converted to a numeric value by the rules of one of the functions declared in the header `<cstdlib>`:
>
> For a signed integer value, the function `strtoll`.

I won't go into *too* much detail on the way `strtoll` works since it would require stepping through quite a few sections of ISO C99 as well. Suffice to say that it ends up at section `6.4.4 Constants` which states the allowable characters to have in an integer, and where the character `.` makes no appearance at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> input_var;
```

This is an operation of the operator `>>` and this operator return cin. However, when this cin is passed to a conditional statement such as `if` or `while` a special function of the `istreat` is called to evaluate a `true` or `false` value from the `cin`. This function check whether `cin` encounter and `EOR` or it receive a value what it suppose to receive. Remember `>>` is an over loaded operator and in your case the operator is called for an integer value. But, when you input a non integer value (`double` in your case), it detects and results a false.

Though, the result cannot be produce in the opposite way, that is when your `input_var` is double in type and you input an integer, `cin` evaluate it as double, however, `cin` do not truncate the numbers after decimal for `int` variable.